# Perturbations on the pseudoinverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, and its perturbation 
$$
A_p = A + \Delta
$$
is there a way to represent 
$$
(A_p)^{\star}= (A)^{\star} + f(\Delta)
$$
where $(A_p)^{\star}$ ($(A)^{\star}$) is the pseudo-inverse of $A_p$ ($A$)?
What can be said about the spectral norm of $f(\Delta)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

substituting $A_p=A+\Delta$ into the definition $A_p^\star=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}(A_p^\ast A_p+\epsilon I)^{-1}A_p^\ast$, and linearizing in the perturbation $\Delta$, gives $A_p^\star=A^\star+f(\Delta)$ with

$$f(\Delta)= -A^\star\Delta A^\star+
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}(A^\ast A+\epsilon I)^{-1}\Delta^*P+{\rm order}(\Delta^2),$$

with $P=I-AA^\star$ the orthogonal projector onto the range of $A$. If $\Delta^\ast P=0$ the simple result

$$A_p^\star=A^\star-A^\star\Delta A^\star+{\rm order}(\Delta^2)$$

is obtained.

Comment: Thanks! If $A$ is full rank than $\Delta^\ast P=0$, correct? Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: if $A$ is square and full rank, then $P=0$, but not so if $A$ is full row or column rank and non-square.

Comment: I also found here 
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379509005230
this bound on the norms that is nice:
$$
||f(\Delta)|| \leq \mu \max({{||A||_2}^2,{||A_p||_2}^2})||\Delta ||_2
$$
where $\mu$ is a constant

Comment: Isn't $P$ the orthogonal projector onto $\mathcal{R}(A)^\perp$?